# Spring Data JPQL No value specified for parameter

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two classes Post and Tag. These are in a many-to-many relationship and Post has an attribute Set< Tag > tags. I want to return the posts which have all the tags I provide as parameter.

> Example: Post A has tags T1, T2 and T3, post B has tags T1. I provide a set with the tags T1 and T3. As a result, only post A should be returned.

In my **repo interface extending CrudRepository**, I have the following custom query build:

```
@Query(
    value="SELECT p, count(p) AS noEntries 
        FROM Post p WHERE p.tags IN :tags 
        GROUP BY p.id HAVING noEntries = :noTags",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(spe) AS noEntries 
        FROM Post spe WHERE spe.tags IN :tags 
        GROUP BY spe.id HAVING noEntries = :noTags")
Page<Post> findAllByTagsInCustom(Pageable pageable, @Param("tags") Set<Tag> tags, 
    @Param("noTags") int noTags);
```

I am calling the query with

```
posts = repo.findAllByTagsInCustom(pReq, tags, tags.size());
```

where the parameters are type PageRequest (pReq), Set (tags) and int (tags.size()).

When running the request I get

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
```

How do I have to specify the method parameters to make the query work?

Comment: I believe the issue is this part `IN :tags`. As far as i know, You cannot pass a collection as parameter.

Comment: @pvpkiran I've tried a query passing a Set, it works

Comment: tags is correctly populated?

Comment: @firegloves Yes it is. I am using Spring Data JPA 1.11.10 (not v2) if that helps in any way.